# NZEC Runtime error in python 2.7

Tags: runtime-error

Can anyone please help what is causing the NZEC error in python 2.7 
in the below problem. 
Thanks,

https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP

`

```
input_cases = input()
    if input_cases>50:
        exit()
    input_cases = int(input_cases)
    for _ in range(input_cases):
        n = raw_input()
        total_jobs_num,finished_jobs_num = map(int,n.split(" "))
        total_jobs = range(1,total_jobs_num+1)
        finished_jobs = map(int,raw_input().split(" "))
        for item in finished_jobs:
            if item in total_jobs:
                total_jobs.remove(item)
        chef_jobs = [total_jobs[i] for i in range(0,len(total_jobs)) if i%2==0]
        assistant_jobs = [total_jobs[i] for i in range(0,len(total_jobs)) if i%2!=0]
        print " ".join(map(str,chef_jobs))
        print " ".join(map(str,assistant_jobs))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One of the common reasons for NZEC to occur is space left in the input by the setter.
instead of `input_cases = input()` try using `input_cases = int(input().split())`